# Jupyter Notebook Input Cell Margin Issue using jupyter-themes

Tags: jupyter-notebook, themes, editor

I have a consistent issue using the jupyter-themes package for Jupyter notebooks, in which the input cell cuts off several pixels from the right margin. I have tried manipulating the cell width (-cellw) and the padding/border of the cell using Page Inspect to no avail. Here is a screenshot with the issue highlighted by the red box:

[Jupyter Margin Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG03m.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

editing `custom.css` file in `.jupyter/custom/custom.css` helped me.

In `div.CodeMirror-lines`, set the `padding-left` parameter to smaller value or zero.

```
div.CodeMirror-lines {
 padding-bottom: .9em;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: .5em;
 padding-top: .7em;
}
```

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/issues/461#issuecomment-1294217735).